# Methods for printing without adding control characters in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I have been using the function `sys.stdout.write(string)` but I was wondering if there is another method for this purpose. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry, i forget, python 2.7

Comment: Maybe is better to say "without control characters"... @sweeneyrod

Comment: Maybe, that seemed less clear to me, as in Python 2.x the only things printed after a `print` statement are newlines and spaces, but I won't change it back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python 3.x:

```
print(string, end="")
```

Python 2.x:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print(string, end="")
```

or

```
print string,    # This way adds a space at the end.
```

From the second answer of the duplicate question, I got this idea:

Instead of something like this:

```
>>> for i in xrange(10):
        print i,
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

you might be able to do this:

```
>>> numbers = []
>>> for i in xrange(10):
       numbers.append(i)
>>> print "".join(map(str, numbers))
12345678910
```

I would recommend `import`ing `print_function`. Or (tongue-in-cheek answer) upgrading to Python 3.x!

Comment: Thank you, the problem with this is that i also don't want an extra space, i'll edit my question ;)